How to deal with multiple DbContext's and UnitOfWorks
I'm currently trying to introduce the Unit of Work pattern in my .NET application, in order to create a transactional behavior for MediatR:
public sealed class TransactionalBehavior<TCommand, TResponse>(
    ILogger<TransactionBehavior<TCommand, TResponse>> logger,
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    : IBehavior<TCommand, TResponse>
    where TCommand : class, ICommand<TResponse>
    where TResponse : class
{
    private readonly ILogger<TransactionBehavior<TCommand, TResponse>> _logger = logger;

    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(
        TCommand request,
        RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using var transaction = await _unitOfWork.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);

        _logger.LogInformation("Started transaction.");

        try
        {
            var response = await next();

            await transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            await transaction.RollbackAsync(cancellationToken);

            throw;
        }
    }
}

The problem is that I got one DbContext for each module, which all implement the IUnitOfWork on it's own. Therefore I got multiple IUnitOfWork's in my dependency container.
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    public Task<IDbContextTransaction> BeginTransactionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

Here is one of the DbContext's as an example:
internal sealed class AuctionhouseDbContext(
    DbContextOptions<AuctionhouseDbContext> options)
    : DbContext(options),
    IUnitOfWork
{
    public const string Schema = "auctionhouse";

    // DbSet<T>'s here...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(
        ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(Schema);

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }

    public async Task<IDbContextTransaction> BeginTransactionAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return await Database.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}

Now the question, how can I change the Unit of Work pattern, so that the MediatR behavior resolves the correct IUnitOfWork? I already thought of a generic IUnitOfWork, but I am not sure if this is the most suitable solution.
Does anybody knows how to solve my problem? Thanks in advance

So ... what do you inject in the actual Request/Response handler? Because that class must have knowledge what dbcontext it needs. That knowledge needs to be present in your behavior class as well.

I inject a repository, which is always coupled to the module / dbcontext. Could I forward this information to the behavior?

That repository has a typed interface I hope, so that type can be used as well to make the IUnitOfWork unique, that unique IUnitOfWork can then inherit from IUnitOfWork so you can keep that interface for common use across modules.

I'm not quite sure if I get you right. Why would the repository have any impact on how the IUnitOfWork is beeing resolved, since it's implemented by the Dbcontext's? If I am wrong here, could you please provide an example?

The repository appears to determine the dbcontext, so that needs to be the combination as well to resolve a generic typed IUnitOfWork.
